# Putting arm on a married woman's waist during photo

Tags: etiquette

How appropriate is it as a single guy to put his arm on a married woman's waist during a photo?  Does this count as a friendly gesture or inappropriate behavior?

Comment: Can you add some context? What location/culture? Do you know her, how well?

Comment: Hi pi a! Welcome to IPS. We can't tell whether something is appropriate because that is opinion based for most of the time. Do you wish to ask her whether that bothered her you did it?

Comment: How do you think about doing this when not during a photo? Probably you wouldn't have asked if you thought it is always appropriate :-) So why would the photo situation change that?

Answer (score 3):

If she's not given you permission to touch her, you likely shouldn't. This is a pretty intimate touch - why do you feel it's needed? What do you gain from it, how does it make the photo better?

Your best bet, if you really feel you have to do this, is to ask her what she's comfortable with - as this is going to vary from person to person. Whatever she says, respect it.

Comment: There are also similar but less intimate places for your arms, that are usually no problem (citation needed) - over the shoulders or on the back.